# ros node for mecanum/omniwheel steering

Tags: ros, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a ros node configured to drive a robot with an omniwheel setup? I'd like to import such a node and use it to simulate and test a robot with that type of wheel configuration.

Thanks,
-Ethan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37078/ros-node-for-mecanum/omniwheel-steering/) by [Intellethan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2518/intellethan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The PR2 navigation systems should work relatively well with mechanum wheels.  You will need to write the low level driver to convert the /cmd_vel into velocity commands for your motors, which is specific to your geometry.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0